# Difference between session_set_cookie_params(seconds) and ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", seconds)

Tags: php, session, cookies

Can anyone please tell me the exact difference between these two:

1. `session_set_cookie_params(seconds)`
2. `ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", seconds)`

I have read at several places that to increase PHP session timeout, we need to do following setting in our script:

`ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", seconds);`

Additionally, we also need to tell client to remember session id for specific time. So I am not sure that which one to use - 1 or 2 (above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_set_cookie_params(seconds)` and `ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", seconds)` both set the lifetime of a session cookie, which determines how long the cookie, and therefore the session, will remain valid on the client's browser.

`session_set_cookie_params(seconds)` sets the lifetime of the cookie for the current session, whereas `ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", seconds)` sets the lifetime of the cookie for all future sessions.

`ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", seconds);` is used to set the maximum lifetime of a session. This setting determines how long a session can remain inactive before it is garbage collected by PHP. This setting is important, because if the user's cookie lifetime is longer than the session's lifetime, the user will be able to access the session even if the session data has been removed by the garbage collector.

In general, you should use both `session_set_cookie_params(seconds)` and `ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", seconds);` to increase the PHP session timeout. The first sets the cookie lifetime for the current session, and the second sets the maximum lifetime for all future sessions. This way you are instructing the client to remember the session id for a specific time and also you are making sure that the session data is not garbage collected before the cookie expires.

Comment: Very well explained! I got it all now. So in short I should use the combination of `ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", seconds);` and `session_set_cookie_params(seconds)` to increase PHP session timeout according to my need. And moreover seconds value must be same in both functions (settings). Thanks.

Comment: Important to note that `gc_maxlifetime` is actual a _minimum_ lifetime, this option was named rather confusingly. After this amount of time has passed since the session was last accessed, the garbage collector is _allowed_ to remove the session data file. But since the GC is triggered randomly, there is no guarantee _when_ that might happen.

Comment: (So if one ever needs a session that _must_ expire after a given time, that needs implementing individually, by storing a timestamp into the session, and then explicitly destroying that session next time it gets used, when the desired amount of time has passed.)

Comment: @CBroe, can you please give me an example with code for your last comment?